# Agregar mas campos en un select con pluck laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, vistas

Hola buenas quiero mostrar mas datos en un select con el metodo pluck, alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Resulta que tengo una tabla Curso, que tiene nombre y tipo como atributos. Quiero darle un curso a un alumno, pero con el pluck que tengo solo me muestra el nombre del curso, quiero que aparezca con el tipo tambien en el select.

Este es mi controllador

```
public function edit($id) 
{
    $alumno = Alumno::find($id);

    $cursos = Curso::orderBy('id','ASC')->pluck('nombre','id');

    $alumno->curso; 

    $apoderados = Apoderado::orderBy('id','ASC')->pluck('nombre','id'); 
    $alumno->apoderado;  

    return view('alumnos.edit')->with('alumno', $alumno)->with('cursos',$cursos)->with('apoderados',$apoderados);
}
```

como puedo concatenar ese nombre del curso con el tipo?? ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso lo mejor es crear un Accessor con los atributos que necesitas: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

```
/**
 * Obtener el nombre y tipo de curso.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNameAndTypeAttribute()
{
    return $this->tipo . ' ' . $this->nombre;
}
```

En pluck lo llamas así:

```
...->pluck('name_and_type','id');
```

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name_and_type' in 'field list' (SQL: select `name_and_type`, `id` from `cursos` order by `id` asc) Me dice que no la encuentra, que hice mal? ese accesor lo coloque en el modelo Curso estara bien??

Comment: La verdad no sé que hayas hecho mal, siempre me han funcionado sin ningún inconveniente los accessors. Tal vez agrégale el get() a la consulta, para garantizar que se está generando la colección. `Curso::orderBy('id','ASC')->get()->pluck('name_and_type','id');`

Comment: perfect, gracias maestro

Comment: Recuerda que si te sirvió la respuesta, puedes marcarla como aceptada.